# Assign ID to a data frame if all 10 columns values is the same as another data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes that look something like this:

```
apparentTemperature_id
| id | apparentTemperature | apparentTemperatureMin | ... |
|  1 |         13          |           9            | ... |
|  2 |         48          |           40           | ... |
|  3 |         32          |           24           | ... |
| ...|         ...         |           ...          | ... |

-----------------------------------------------------------

temp
| apparentTemperature | apparentTemperatureMin | ... |
|         32          |           24           | ... |
|         13          |           9            | ... |
|         32          |           24           | ... |
|         ...         |           ...          | ... |
```

This is my current code:

```
temp = pd.concat([apparentTemperature_df, temperature_df], axis=1)
temp_list = []

for i in range (len(temp)):
    for k in range (len(apparentTemperature_id)):
        if temp.iloc[i,0:9].equals(apparentTemperature_id.iloc[k,1:10]):
            temp_list.append(apparentTemperature_id.iloc[k,0])
            break
```

I want to assign IDs to the temp data according to the `apparentTemperature_id`. There are a total of 10 columns to compare.

Since the data has 600,000+ rows and the there are 1000+ ids, the code above takes ages to finish. Is there any faster way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dataframes together using a list of the columns you want to compare. This should be much more performant than iterating through both dataframes with `.iloc` and comparing the values in the columns.

I've modified the samples of your `apparentTemperature_id` and `temp` so that there are some rows where the columns are and aren't the same.

```
apparentTemperature_id = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'apparentTemperature':[13,48,32],'apparentTemperatureMin':[9,40,24]})
apparentTemperature_id['id'] = apparentTemperature_id['id'].astype(str)

#    id  apparentTemperature  apparentTemperatureMin
# 0   1                   13                       9
# 1   2                   48                      40
# 2   3                   32                      24

temp = pd.DataFrame({'apparentTemperature':[13,48,32],'apparentTemperatureMin':[9,40,0]})

#    apparentTemperature  apparentTemperatureMin
# 0                   13                       9
# 1                   48                      40
# 2                   32                       0
```

Then we can merge on `['apparentTemperature','apparentTemperatureMin']` so that the values in these columns are compared between the two dataframes, and use the argument `how='inner'` so that we keep only the rows where the values in these columns are the same (in the merged dataframe, only ids 1 and 2 are kept because they share all the same values in the columns we compared). In your case, you would merge on all 10 columns you want to compare.

```
apparentTemperature_id.merge(temp, on=['apparentTemperature','apparentTemperatureMin'], how='inner')

#   id  apparentTemperature  apparentTemperatureMin
# 0  1                   13                       9
# 1  2                   48                      40
```